# What is the most Pythonic way to convert 0 and 1 strings to boolean?

Tags: python

I’m reading a value from a General Purpose IO (GPIO) configured as Input and it returns a string that is either 0 or 1. I see two easy ways to convertiing it to boolean:

```
bool(int(input_value))
```

or

```
not not int(input_value)
```

Which is most Pythonic? Are there more Pythonic ways then the ones presented above?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are many ways, but I would like to propose the following:

```
{'0': False, '1': True}[input_value]
```

This has the advantage of raising an exception if you ever get a value different to what you expect (because of a bug, a malfunction, an API change etc).

All the other options presented thus far will silently accept any string as input.

Answer (score 0):

If your `input_value` must be `"1"` or `"0"`, and you want your boolean value to be true if it is `"1"`, then you want the boolean expression

```
input_value=="1"
```

E.g.

```
bool_var = (input_value=="1")
```

This will give `True` if `input_value` is equal to `"1"`, and `False` if it is equal to `"0"` (or anything else).